# How to create custom feed group and assign activities to it in getstream.io Meteor?

Tags: meteor, getstream-io

I'm using [Stream Meteor](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-meteor) to create a social app, it has users, pages ..etc.

I can use it to create userFeed, and usertimeline (newsFeed), but I can't figure out how to create and use a new custom feed group, say, page feed, so users can follow each other userFeed, and also follow, pageFeed.

I can create feed groups on getstream.io dashboard, but how to use it and assign activities to it from my meteor app's code?

Answer (score 0):

Our normal architecture suggestion is a user feed (which you have) where all user-generated content would go, a timeline feed (which you have) for following other users' "user" feeds (ie, timeline:ian would follow user:uxe).

Can you elaborate on what the "page feed" is going to be used for? You should be able to follow our JavaScript examples for accessing and adding other activities to different feeds, these won't be Meteor specific.

If all user activity is going to get copied into this page feed and it can be viewable to all users, then you won't need to set up additional following rules. But, we'll need more information before we go that route.

Comment: thanks, the scenario I'm talking about is like on facebook pages, I need a separate feed for each page which the page itself is the actor, so when I follow that pageFeed I get its posts in my timeline.

so if there isn't Meteor specific way to do this I think I will need to do it using the Stream Javascript API, right?